# Jade radio button checked condition

Tags: radio-button, conditional-statements, pug

I have form in Jade file, and I want it to be pre-filled with some values that come from backend.In the form, there are radio buttons for user gender.

```
input(type="radio", name="gender_filter", value="1") Male
input(type="radio", name="gender_filter", value="0") Female
```

Now I also have this variable `gender_param`, and I want the corresponding button to be selected when page loads.
In **PHP**, I could do this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender_filter", value="1" <?php echo ($gender_param==1)?"checked":''; ?>>
```

Is there the corresponding syntax for Jade? Or I need to write it in the long way with line duplicates like

```
- if gender_param==1
   input(type="radio", name="gender_filter", value="1", checked) Male
- else
   input(type="radio", name="gender_filter", value="1") Male
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in jade even simpler than in PHP:

```
input(type="radio", name="gender_filter", value="1", checked=gender=="male")
| Male
input(type="radio", name="gender_filter", value="0", checked=gender=="female")
| Female
```

This code block expects `gender` to be a variable passed from the backend to the view.

Comment: According to this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox it seems your usage of the checked attribute may be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

For Jade: here are a few input types and the shorthand for keeping the checked value once submitting the form, i.e. so you can populate an edit page...

Radio Button:

`input(type="radio" name="stars" value='1' id='stars' checked=theAlbum.rating=='1')`

Select box:

`option(selected = theAlbum.genre) #{theAlbum.genre}`

`option Jazz
 option Rock
 option Rap
 option Dance`

Checkbox:

`checked=theAlbum.checkbox`