# Run time error while typecasting WebDriver to CheckBox

Tags: selenium, checkbox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

In my application, I have a grid with a column for check boxes. The ID of the check boxes for each row differs only by the number after a fixed value. xxxx_0, xxxx_1, ....

In order to select a check box in any row, the row number can be appended to get the complete ID.

My code is like this :

```java
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    CheckBox visible = (CheckBox) driver.findElement(By.id("visibleCheckboxValue_" + i));
    visible.toggle(false);
}
```

This gives me a run time error as "cannot cast Remote webdriver to CheckBox."

Also, if I use cast it as `WebElement`, I cannot use the `toggle(boolean select)` function.

```java
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    WebElement visible = (WebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("visibleCheckboxValue_" + i));
    if(visible.isSelected()) {
        visible.click() // To uncheck the check box
    }
}
```

On a `WebElement`, I can use `.isSelected()` to check if the check box is selected or not, but it always returns false. Even if the check box is selected, it returns false.

Is there any way to cast a Webdriver to CheckBox, so I can use the `toggle()` function effectively ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you are thinking about this the wrong way around.

You are not going to be able to cast it to a `CheckBox`, and I wouldn't expect you to! That's integrating with another API, which Selenium does not do! You shouldn't be casting the result from `.findElement()` at all!

You need to think about *why* you are unable to use the inbuilt functionality and not about how you can mangle it into a different object.

The first thing I would suggest is to explicitly check the "checked" value of the element you are bringing back.

When a `checkbox` is `checked` in HTML, it can be set in a various amount of different ways, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox) StackOverflow question regarding the "right" way to set a checkbox to `checked`. Here, you should be able to see it isn't a simple case of `yes` or `no`.

So check what value the `checked` status is, on that element. I'm not going to do it for you, that's not the point of learning, but psuedo-code:

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(driver.findElement(By.id("visibleCheckboxValue_" + i));
string checkedStatus = checkBox.getAttribute("checked");
// now do some checking...ie. does that string now contain something? yes? it's checked.
```

Now you *should* be able to use the `.isSelected` method, but before we go any further, see if the above works. If so, great, but it means something is broken elsewhere. If not then you should also provide your HTML (with any accompanying JS and CSS that may be relevant) so we can effectively diagnose this issue with you.