# Checkbox not working in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have dynamic check box in my view. But its not working fine its always getting checked
here is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')" id = "@item.UserId"   checked="@(item.IsActive == false ? false : true)" />
```

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Checked` attribute doesn't take `true` or `false` as a value. The sole presence of this attribute makes it checked. You have to remove this attribute if you want element to remain unchecked.

Read more [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')" 
 id = "@item.UserId" checked="@item.IsActive" />
```

Comment: Wrong. The checkbox will be checked if the `checked` attribute is present on the element, no matter what the value is. `checked="true"` and `checked="false"` behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Patryk said - you need to change the way the checked attribute is added. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')" id = "@item.UserId"   @(item.IsActive ? "checked" : "") />
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

### **Approach - 1**

```
@if(item.IsActive)
{
    <input type="checkbox" onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')" 
       id = "@item.UserId" checked="checked" />
}
else
{
    <input type="checkbox" onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')" 
         id = "@item.UserId"/> 
}
```

### **Approach - 2**

You can use below code.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);    // Checked
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);   // Un-Checked
```

If you pay attention to the above code, prop function is used to set the attribute value. You can use JQuery - 1.6 version. Now based upon your condition, you can write Razor code in the JavaScript section like below..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {                   //Some Razor code in JQuery
        var status = "@status" == "True" ? true : false;
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', status);
    });
</script>
```

Server side sample code in View.cshtml

```
@{
    var status = false;
}
```

### **Approach - 3**

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {                   //Some Razor code in JQuery
        var status = "@status" == "True" ? true : false;
        if (!status)
            $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
        else
            $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);

    });
</script>
```

Server side code in cshtml

```
@{
    var status = true;
}
```

If you pay attention to the above JQuery code, I am removing the checked attribute using the `removeAttr` in case status value is false and setting it to true using the `attr` function when status is true.

Comment: @user2433270 : Did you check this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 @{
  if (ViewBag.IsActive)
  {
    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.UserId" checked onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')"/>
  }
  else
  {
    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.UserId" onclick = "InActiveUser('@item.UserId')"/>
  }
}
```