# cant insert data into postgresDB in php

Tags: php, postgresql

im having trouble inserting my data's from textbox into postgresdb.
my insert into tbl_ingredients is working fine but my insert into tbl_item is having a troubles can't figure it out how and where?

```
Connect();      

            $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_item VALUES('$itemname', '$highthreshold', '$lowthreshold', '$Qpunit', '$description', '$date');";
            $iteminfo = pg_query($sql);

            $sql1="SELECT MAX(itemid) as newid FROM tbl_item;";
            $iden_new = pg_query($sql1);
                $fetched_row = pg_fetch_row($iden_new,NULL,PGSQL_BOTH);
                $newid=$fetched_row['newid'];

            $sql2="INSERT INTO tbl_ingredient VALUES('$newid', '$Brandname');";
            $ingredients = pg_query($sql2);

            CloseDB();

            if(!$sql)
            {
            $sucmsg = "Successfully added new Item, ".ucfirst($itemname)."!";       
            echo $sucmsg;           
            }
            else
            {
            echo "error in saving data";
            }
```

table structure:
**tbl_item**

itemid>itemname>highquantitythreshold>lowquantitythreshold>qntyperunit>Itemtype>description>dateadded

**tbl_ingredient**

itemid>brandname

im getting wamp "Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "Strawberry" LINE 1: INSERT INTO tbl_item VALUES('Strawberry', '6', '3', '1300gra... ^ in D:\Wamp\wamp\www\Php\CTea\AddItem.php on line 247"

can someone lend me a helping hand  thanks!.

Comment: What is your table structure for `tbl_item`? Does it have an `id` or other integer column for the first column? Since `'Strawberry'` is not an integer it is failing. May need to do `VALUES(NULL,'$itemname',...`. For the 2nd issue, change `if(!sql)` to `if(!$sql)`.

Comment: my bad forget to put table structure also on if(!$sql)..about the Null do i need to put **Null** even if its serial data type on postgress?

Comment: see my answer about using `NULL` or specifying the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to use `NULL` ->

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_item VALUES(NULL, '$itemname', '$highthreshold', '$lowthreshold', '$Qpunit', '$description', '$date');";
```

**OR**

You need to specify the columns you are inserting into ->

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_item (itemname, highquantitythreshold, lowquantitythreshold, qntyperunit, description, dateadded)  VALUES('$itemname', '$highthreshold', '$lowthreshold', '$Qpunit', '$description', '$date');";
```

Without the `NULL` or column name, the database does not know that you are skipping the first column - `itemid` - so it will try to insert the 1st value into that column.

---

from the manual - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html

> The target column names can be listed in any order. If no list of
>   column names is given at all, the default is all the columns of the
>   table in their declared order; or the first N column names, if there
>   are only N columns supplied by the VALUES clause or query. The values
>   supplied by the VALUES clause or query are associated with the
>   explicit or implicit column list left-to-right.
>
> Each column not present in the explicit or implicit column list will
>   be filled with a default value, either its declared default value or
>   null if there is none.

Comment: can i ask u 1 more thing how can i keep radio button checked? im using
`<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>`

but every time i press submit it always goes back to its default mode
(unchecked).

Comment: That should work as you have it. The only thing I can think of is to make sure the field name is correct, as I see that your column name in your query is `Itemtpe`. You could also check the html source code in the browser to make sure there is not any syntax errors.

Comment: my html code for radio.
`<input type="radio" name="Itemtype" id="Miscellaneous" value="Miscellaneous" <?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked="checked" ';?> 
> `
from what i think nothing seems off but still not working.

Comment: oh my bad...i already get it working thanks for the help. what im having trouble now is that my radio button wont return checked after submit.

Comment: Based off your html code, I don't see why it is not working. You could also try just `checked` -> `<input type="radio" name="Itemtype" id="Miscellaneous" value="Miscellaneous" <?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked';?>  >` (although does not work with XHTML) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852002/689579

Comment: still wont return checked... :( im getting pissed on this radio thing for a while now, ive tried every possible way i know but still wont return checked.

Comment: can help me with this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347677/how-to-properly-make-drop-down-list-menu-for-my-tbl-item-in-php?noredirect=1#comment33966008_22347677