# How to properly make drop down list menu for my tbl_item in php

Tags: php, function

Im having trouble with my drop down list menu its keeps getting wamp error.
my drop down list menu will be from the itemname of tbl_item(postgresDB)

funcContainer.php page

```
function DropdownListMenu ($label, $name, $sql, $value, $item, $submit_name, $submit_val)
{
    echo $label."&nbsp;<select name='$name'>";
    $rs = pg_query($sql);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($rs, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row[$value]."'";
        if ($row[$value] == $_POST[$name])
            echo ' selected';
        echo ">".$row[$item]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>&nbsp;";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='".$submit_name."' value='".$submit_val."' />";
}
```

search.php page

```
<?php 
require_once("funcContainer.php");
Connect();


$sql = "Select itemid, itemname from tbl_item";
DropdownListMenu ("Select Item", "Item", $sql, 'itemid', 'itemname', "Submit", "Search");?>
```

tbl_item structure:
itemid>itemname>highquantitythreshold>lowquantitythreshold>qpunit>...

wamp error:
SCREAM: ERROR suppresion ignored & Undefined Index Item in D:.....
can someone please lend me a helping hand here again :) thanks!.

Comment: I apologize yesterday I took the day off of work and didn't get on a computer... If you need my help if you use the @ sign then my name on a post it "should" notify me of the post... At least that is what I have heard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On initial page load `$_POST[$name]` (or more specifically `$_POST['Item']` may not be set. So you will want to check if it is set before using.

Change

```
if ($row[$value] == $_POST[$name])
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST[$name]) && $row[$value] == $_POST[$name])
```