# Using [checked] or [checked="checked"]

Tags: html

Basically a simple question I'm not really sure where to search after;

Is it safe to write `checked` as an attribute instead of `checked="checked"` without becoming incompatible with certain browsers? This also includes `selected`, `disabled`, `readonly` and so on.

It just feels like mindless repetition to type in the same thing twice because of habit, so if anyone knows if this can be skipped without any consequences or not, please share your knowledge.

**Example**:

Can I always use `<input type="checkbox" checked />` instead of `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`?

This answer is answered to a certain extent in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox). But apart from XHTML, I don't see any answers regarding browser compatibility and the like.

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to HTML attributes as opposed to CSS selectors? Your title uses CSS attribute selector syntax which is not the same thing as HTML attributes, but your tags say [html].

Comment: @Nicolò Monili: That question is about DOM scripting, not HTML markup. Not really a dupe.

Comment: Good answers, however they address what you _should_ type. Not, what I can spot, what you _have_ to type to be functional in most browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock I added an example to clarify. Just used it's css reference for easier title.

Comment: OK, because the answer differs greatly if you were asking about CSS.

Comment: it is good practice to write in this format. `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

Comment: I've heard it's good practice, but for what reason given? It just feels repetitive and unnecessary.

Comment: @Robin Castlin: The *only* difference is HTML vs XHTML syntax. You either use `checked` and close it with `>`, or `checked="checked"` and close it with `/>`. There is literally **no other difference**. Browsers handle both of them the same way. Anybody telling you to use XHTML markup simply because "it's just good practice" without explaining this difference probably doesn't know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the following, you won't be able to get the value of checked as there is no value.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

When you use the following, you can get the checked value of the checkbox. This might be helpful in fetching the checkbox checked value using javascript or jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: I just tested this in Firefox and Chrome, and both returned the same answer: http://jsfiddle.net/3HJE4/ Are you using another browser?

Comment: Yes that would give the same output.

Comment: The `checked` attribute does not have a value. Maybe that's why you can't get one.

Comment: you cant get one, because there is no value attribute in input