# how to check multiple checkbox if i have multiple values in one field

Tags: php

i try this but it will only work when there is one value in the field.when multiple values  in the field it will not work please help me get out of this..

Action

```
      if($row2->genre=='action'){echo 'checked=checked';} ?>>
     <?php //echo $row2->genre;?>
    adventure<input type='checkbox'name='chkbox[]'value='adventure'<?php if($row2->genre=='adventure'){echo 'checked=checked';} ?> >
```

Comment: You can just say "checked", you know. no need for "checked=checked", that's just silly.

Comment: @MightyPork: It usually will work, but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox

Comment: sir my database field contain adventure,Scfi retrieved nw i want the two check boxes check how will i do it

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yeah, but nobody uses XHTML anyway, so why not keep it readable.

Comment: it works on one value will value eg id adventure stored in database it will check the adventure checkbox.. but proble in multiple values

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that $row2->genre is a string containing multiple genres, then

```
if(stristr($row2->genre,'action')){ echo /*whatever*/; }
```

whether you use checked=checked or just checked depends on your doctype.