# how to set radio button checked?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to set **radio button checked** by using follwing code

```
<td><%if ((retrieveId != 0) && (retrieveId == agency.getId())) {%>
  <input type="radio" id="agencyradio" name="agencyradio" checked="checked">
  <%} else {%>
  <input type="radio" id="agencyradio" name="agencyradio" >
    <%}%></td>
```

But it is not working.This is one of column of table.Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the else statement is triggering, so check and make sure that `agency.getId()` is actually equal to `retrieveId`

Comment: @SterlingArcher i placed checked="checked" in else input tag and removed from if ,then also it is not working

Comment: i am using datatable instead of simple table

Answer (score 0):

The ID must be unique
So change your id

try Below code

```
<td><%if ((retrieveId != 0) && (retrieveId == agency.getId())) {%>
    <input type="radio" id="agencyradio" name="agencyradio" checked>
<%} else {%>
    <input type="radio" id="agencyradio_one" name="agencyradio" >
 <%}%></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<td><%if ((retrieveId != 0) && (retrieveId == agency.getId())) {%>
  <input type="radio" id="agencyradio" name="agencyradio" checked>
  <%} else {%>
  <input type="radio" id="agencyradio" name="agencyradio" >
    <%}%></td>
```

Comment: i am using datatable instead of simple table

Answer (score -1):

Use EL language. Avoid scriplets in JSP

```
 <input type="radio" id="agencyradio" name="agencyradio" ${retrieveId ne 0 && retrieveId eq agency.id?'checked=\"checked\"':''}">
```

You should have agency in any of this scope page/request/session/application

Comment: The whole attribute `checked="checked"` must be conditional.

Comment: Just tested it in FF33 and the whole attribute must be removed to prevent checked... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852002/354831) you have more information.