# Set checked attribute in Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms, checked

I try to set `checked` attribute for `<input type="checkbox"/>`:

```
checked="<%#Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsOperationPerformed")) ? "checked" : string.Empty%>"
```

But I get an error

> Argument type ‘string’ is not assignable to parameter type ‘bool’

`IsOperationPerformed` of type `Boolean`.

How can I add `cheched` attribute?

Comment: What do you mean you got an error "IsOperationPerformed of type Boolean."? What is the exact error message you got.

Comment: Can you try wrapping single quotes around attribute, as you can see that quotes here are not escaped properly.

Comment: @BenRobinson, no. I said that IsOperationPerformed has type bool, whereas i get error in such convert

Comment: OK so what was the error you got?

Comment: @BenRobinson, "Argument type ‘string’ is not assignable to parameter type ‘bool’"

Comment: make sure `IsOperationPerformed` is not NULL.

Comment: or make sure IsOperationPerformed is boolen on database

Comment: @ArindamNayak, you were right. i didn't get value from database

Comment: You can use `isnull(col,false)` in select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, [CheckBox should be equal to either true or false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) and not checked or empty. Try changing it and revert if problem still occurs.
Hope i helped.

```
checked="<%#Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsOperationPerformed")) ? TRUE : FALSE%>"
```

Comment: this helps, thanks. However i always think that chechbox can be checked or cheched="checked"

Comment: But as OP has said ,  it was showing some error, it has to do with some code. But `checked=checked` also works.- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox

Comment: @Alok, you havn't solved OP's original problem , and checked with any value will always work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox

Comment: @ArindamNayak thats html and i dont know it works with asp.net or not but correct way is it should be true or false. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I will surely try and find out whether checked="checked" works or not but the code was wrong as string.empty will return empty to check...And yes only checked works to set default to check.