# Ticking Checkboxs by Default

Tags: html, css

I have the following and want to ensure the tick boxes are enabled by default.

```
<div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input name="validation" type="checkbox">Validation
        </label>

        <label>
          <input name="steps" type="checkbox">Steps
        </label>

        <label>
          <input name="subticket" type="checkbox">Subticket
        </label>
  </div>
```

Whats the best method for achieving this ?

Comment: google is your friend...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the proper value for a checked attribute of an HTML checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox)

Comment: Very low effort put in research.

Answer (score 1):

You can use checked property with value true i.e. checked="true" or you can use checked only without any value, because by default it will consider true.

```html
<div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input name="validation" type="checkbox" checked>Validation
        </label>

        <label>
          <input name="steps" type="checkbox" checked>Steps
        </label>

        <label>
          <input name="subticket" type="checkbox" checked>Subticket
        </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`checked`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox.attrs.checked) attribute:

```
<label>
  <input name="validation" type="checkbox" checked>Validation
</label>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7syj767j/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'checked' property

```
<input type='checkbox' checked>
```

OR

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="validation" type="checkbox" checked />Validation
```

Add attribute `checked` to the input