# Html invalid value for type

Tags: html, checkbox, types

I am working on a piece of html and the code is giving me a " Bad value checkbox for attribute type on element input." Here is the line of code that is throwing the error

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove role attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" name="yourname"  checked>
```

use any of these

> ```
> <input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked>
> <input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked="">
> <input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked="yes">
> <input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked="blue">
> <input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked="false">
> ```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852002/3623027) answer for more

Comment: Thank you for the response but it still gave me the " Bad value checkbox for attribute type on element input" when I ran it through the w3 validation

Comment: i guess problem is with your role attribute. try removing it