# Checkbox is not getting checked inside webgrid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

When I run this code then all CheckBoxes are showing unchecked.

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<div id="gridContent" style=" padding:20px; ">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        columns:
            grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID</text>),
            grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name", format: @<text>@item.FirstName</text> ),
            grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last Name", format: @<text>@item.LastName</text>),
            grid.Column(header: "IsActive",
            format: @<text><input id="select" class="box" name="select" type="checkbox" value="@item.IsActive" /></text>,
            style: "text-center checkbox-width")
            ))
</div>
```

**IsActive** is always having true as value. Model class looks like:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public IList<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        string connectionStringName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentDBContext"].ConnectionString;
        IList<Student> _Student = new List<Student>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringName))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
              "SELECT ID, FirstName,LastName,IsActive FROM Student;", connection);

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    _Student.Add(new Student()
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString()),
                        FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                        LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString(),
                        IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsActive"])
                    });
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        return _Student;
    }

    public Student()
    {
    }
}
```

Just do not understand where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<input id="select" class="box" name="select" type="checkbox" value="@item.IsActive" />
```

You should do:

```
<input id="select" class="box" name="select" type="checkbox" @(item.IsActive ? "checked='checked'" : "") value="@item.IsActive" />
```

More information about how to check a checkbox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox).

Comment: what to store as value for checkbox?

Comment: You can still store the value as true or false. This is important for submitting the form, but this doesn't check the checkbox. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This might display the initial checked state, but it will not post correctly (if the initial value is `false`, and the user then checks the checkbox, it will post back `false` (not `true`)