# Unchecked Radio Button aspnet mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a radio button that can started unchecked, but even when the condition is false, it's writting the checked attribute in html and the browser show checked

`@Html.RadioButton("radio", "1", new { @checked = (condition) })
@Html.RadioButton("radio", "2", new { @checked = (condition) })`

Comment: Because you have `@checked = (condition)`.Its the presence of the checked attribute that determines if a radio button is checked (`checked="checked"` or `checked="false"` or `checked="AnythingAtAll` all mean the the same thing - it will be checked

Comment: What are you wanting to do here. Its the value of your property `radio` that determines what is checked. If its `1` the first one will be selected an if its `2` the 2nd will be, otherwise none will be. What is the `type` and value or your property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper use will be this

```
@Html.RadioButton("radio", "1",  (condition))
```

According to [RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538529(v=vs.111).aspx)
, radio button constructor defined as

```
RadioButton(string name,Object value, bool isChecked)
```

which will produce

```
<!-- isChecked is true. --> 
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value" checked="checked" />
<!-- isChecked is false. --> 
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value" />
```

I think you are trying to use new htmlattribute which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The overload you are using for `@Html.RadioButton` takes HTML attributes. When you specify `checked = (condition)` you are specifying the attribute `checked` with a value.

With HTML inputs it's not a case of setting the `checked` value to true or false. The very presence of the `checked` attribute means the control is checked. So just `checked`, or `checked = ""`, and even `checked = "false"` will all result in a checked control.

See also this related question: [What's the proper value for a checked attribute of an HTML checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox)

In your case you would be better off with the overload [HtmlHelper.RadioButton Method (String, Object, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538529(v=vs.111).aspx) which lets you specify a boolean value for whether of not the control is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your condition on the controller and supply boolean via ViewBag

@Html.RadioButton("TestButton", "Value", (Boolean)ViewBag.DefaultValue)