# Checkbox with initialValues of true is being displayed without check on refresh

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-edge, redux-form

I am seeing this in Edge and IE.
I have a checkbox which is being initialized using initialValues to true.
On first visit its is displayed correctly as checked with a value of true, however after refreshing the page via the browser, the checkbox is not checked but still has a value of true. As i can continue to refresh the page the checkbox continues to switch in this way checked then unchecked on next refresh. redux form 7.2.3 react 15.6.2.

Thanks

Comment: The value of a checkbox and whether it is checked are two different things. Are you controlling the `checked` property?

Comment: Thanks Roy. No not setting checked specifically as examples and every other browser except edge and ie11 seem happy with initial value of true alone. Is this in redux-form docs please?

Comment: Looking at this: https://jsfiddle.net/e0t60u1n/ (unless I'm misunderstanding your statement) FF/Chrome/Edge all render the same. The way, per spec to state that a checkbox should be checked is using the `checked` property as @RoyJ stated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#Value) of a checkbox is what will be associated with its name *if it is checked*. Checking a checkbox should not change the value, it should [change the `checked` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox).

This is not specific to redux-form, it is just how form elements are intended to work. It looks like redux-form wants to use `value` instead, and [it doesn't work right](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/334).

In any case, I think you want to specifically handle the `checked` property with something like `checked={value}`.

Comment: Again thanks for your input on this however there is something more going on here with the field component in redux-form as event setting `<Field name="test" type="checkbox" component="input" value={true} checked={true} />` i can recreate the above behaviour. will post issue at gh. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response but i think there is a something else IE/Edge and redus-form related specific going wrong with checkboxes. I have created the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2vn685yy0) and although this works as expected directly from the sandbox in Edge, if i download this and run it off a server i can recreate consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Roy's answer is correct. Adding some redux-form context, passing `checked` to a `Field` component will override the normal behaviour. The normal behaviour is to compare if the value stored in redux-form's state is the same as the value prop specified on `Field` if so the checked prop is true.

So for example if the store state is `values: { test: true }` and your `Field` has `value={true}` then the end result is the checked prop is true.

The `F5` refreshing toggle most likely suggests that your values initialization is changing on each refresh. It's hard to help you beyond a general statement like this without clear reproduction steps.