# How to check checboxes in a php table?

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

So I have a guestlist in a PHP table, but I want to check the guests that have arrived.

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM guestlist LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Check-in</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["name"]. "</td>
            <td> " . $row["surname"]. "</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' class='get_value' name='checkbox'  ".$row["check-in"]. "></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' ".$row["submit"]. "></td>
          </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Nothing there shows your checkboxes. ..

Comment: Are you just looking for the `checked` attribute for an `<input type="checkbox" />` element?

Comment: $sql='SELECT * FROM guestlist LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);



  echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Check-in</th></tr>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td> " . $row["surname"]. "</td><td><input type='checkbox' class='get_value' name='checkbox'  ".$row["check-in"]. "></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' ".$row["submit"]. "></td></tr>";

Comment: what does `$row["check-in"]` contain? is it a bool, a string?

Comment: Can you dump `$row`. And why do you tagged ajax ?

Comment: it contains checkboxes...

Comment: because someone told me that i can do it with ajax

Comment: What's a PHP Table? You're showing some SQL code so that would be a database table - but then you mention checkboxes, which would be an HTML Table... could you add some clarity on what it is you're *actually* trying to do?

Comment: @megi Didn't know there was a datatype called checkboxes...

Comment: i have a php table with the id,name and surname of some guests, i have a another row in the table with checkboxes. all i want to do is check the names of the guests who have arrived. i mean i check them and when i refresh the page, the checkbox does not have the tick in it

Comment: In future, please format you code example so it is easily readable and if at all possible without needing to scroll into next week to see the end of a line. That will also make it easier for you to read and **debug** yourself

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what `$row['check-in']` contains but you just need use html `checked`:

```
if($row["check-in"]=='on'){
    $checked=" checked='checked'";
}else{
    $checked='';
}
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='get_value' name='checkbox'  ".$checked."></td>";
```

Edit: to use in loop:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='get_value' id='checkbox[]' name='checkbox[]'  ".$checked."></td>";
```

Comment: Just to be sure it works on all browsers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox

Comment: no it did not help me...the checkboxes are still uncheck when i refresh the page

Comment: You need to change the `'on'` to whatever you are looking for in the database

Comment: @megi it is probably because of `on` in `if($row["check-in"]=='on'){` you must compair to what `check-in` contains. I hope that `check-in` are not ton of unique values. ..

Comment: it contains empty boxes where you can put a tick to show if a guest has arrived or not

Comment: @megi what does `empty boxes` means?

Comment: can you please `var_dump($row)` so we can see the data - this is getting us no where

Comment: @megi what value `$row["check-in"]` contains when guest have arrived and what value when guest has not arrived?

Comment: i have not include any values. So all i want is a table with the names of some guests and to be able to check the names that have arrived.

Comment: @megi if you are not able to click checkboxes you need to use `[]` for name  `name='checkbox[]'`

Comment: i did it, i click in the check box but when i refresh the page, the box is empy again

Comment: Do you save the data after checking it in?

Comment: @megi you need to save data