# Checked checkbox does not send a Boolean value to the database

Tags: html, django

I created a custom signup page.

I want the user to have, by default, two Boolean fields, `is_nhs` and `agree_conditions`.

However, the `checked` attribute in my HTML is not working. The database does receive it. In fact, if I log in as superuser in the Django dashboard, the attribute `is_nhs` and `agree_conditions` are always set to false (red cross).

**My custom user model:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  organization = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  postcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  agree_conditions = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_nhs = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

**My signup.html**

```
 <form>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" checked="checked">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1" name="agree_conditions">Agree conditions</label>
        <a href="{% url 'conditions'%}">Click here to see the conditions you are accepting</a>
      <div class="form-check" hidden>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="is_nhs" id="exampleRadios1" value="Yes" required checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Yes
      </label>
    </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I tried to change unsuccessfully to `checked_attribute` following this guide:
*[What's the proper value for a checked attribute of an HTML checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851868/whats-the-proper-value-for-a-checked-attribute-of-an-html-checkbox)*

Moreover, I find it strange that `agree_conditions` (in my model's field) shows a red cross (in the admin/superuser dashboard) even if it is by `default=True`.

Comment: Is any data arriving from your post?

Comment: Yes, `first_name`, `last_name` etc., they work. In fact, you cannot signup unless you fill all the fields, otherwise the signup page will reaload. Therefore, `is_nhs` and `agree_conditions` receive always `False` or the signup page will keep reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox input does not have a `name` attribute; in fact, it looks like you've mistakenly put the name attribute on the label. It should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="agree_conditions" id="exampleCheck1" checked="checked">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Agree conditions</label>
```

(Note, you should really be using a Django form class for this.)

Comment: Thanks, m only concern about Django forms is that I do not understand clearly from the documentation how I can add boostrap etc. to them.